# Invalid or unexpected token in JQuery with Blazor and ASP.NET Core

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a problem with jQuery, I want to pass two parameters in different functions but I don't succeed and get an error on the console:

> Invalid or unexpected token

This is my code:

```
@model UsersWithCoursesViewModel

@{
    this.ViewData["Title"] = "Evaluation";
    int counter = 1;
}

<h1 class="text-center mt-3 mb-3">@this.ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Username</th>
        <th scope="col">Course</th>
        <th scope="col">Grade</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var course in Model.Courses)
    {
        <tr>
            <th>@counter</th>
            <td>@course.AddedByUser</td>
            <td>@course.CourseName</td>
            <td class="d-flex justify-content-between" id="evaluation">
                @course.Grade
                <a class="btn btn-warning" onclick="addInput(@course.CourseId, '@course.AddedByUserId')">Change</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        counter++;
    }
</tbody>
</table>

@section Scripts { 
<script>
    function addInput(courseId, addedByUserId) {
        $("#evaluation").remove(".a").text(null).prepend("<label for='evaluation_input'>Evaluate</label><input id='evaluation_input' type='number' /><a class='btn btn-warning' onclick='evaluates(" + courseId + ", " + addedByUserId + ")'>Save</a>")
    }

    function evaluates(courseId, addedByUserId) {
        const evaluation = $("#evaluation_input").val();
        console.log(userId)
    }
</script>
}
```

When I click on the button with event `addClick()`, everything is OK (the input appears and `courseId` and `addedByUserId` are written in the console), but when I click the button with the name Save and "evaluates" function, I get that error "Invalid or unexpected token". I think the problem is coming from `addedByUserId` variable, it is GUID, and when I change this

```
onclick='evaluates(" + courseId + ", " + addedByUserId + ")
```

to this

```
"evaluates(" + courseId + ", " + 5 + ")"
```

there is no problem (the console outputs "5").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is due to fact that you need to wrap the parameter values of the inline event handler in quotes. These quotes themselves need to be escaped as well so that they don't interfere with both the JS string you're building and also the syntax of the HTML attribute you're building. The correct syntax would be this:

```js
function addInput(courseId, addedByUserId) {
  $("#evaluation").remove(".a").text(null).prepend('<label for="evaluation_input">Evaluate</label><input id="evaluation_input" type="number" /><a class="btn btn-warning" onclick="evaluates(\'' + courseId + '\', \'' + addedByUserId + '\')">Save</a>');
}

function evaluates(courseId, addedByUserId) {
  const evaluation = $("#evaluation_input").val();
  console.log(evaluation)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Username</th>
      <th scope="col">Course</th>
      <th scope="col">Grade</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>AddedByUser_1</td>
      <td>CourseName_1</td>
      <td class="d-flex justify-content-between" id="evaluation">
        Grade_1
        <a class="btn btn-warning" onclick="addInput(1, 'AddedByUserId_1')">Change</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>AddedByUser_2</td>
      <td>CourseName_2</td>
      <td class="d-flex justify-content-between" id="evaluation">
        Grade_2
        <a class="btn btn-warning" onclick="addInput(2, 'AddedByUserId_2')">Change</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>AddedByUser_3</td>
      <td>CourseName_3</td>
      <td class="d-flex justify-content-between" id="evaluation">
        Grade_3
        <a class="btn btn-warning" onclick="addInput(3, 'AddedByUserId_3')">Change</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

*- Update -*

However this is rather ugly code, due to the building of the inline event handler at runtime, and also has a bug whereby no matter which 'Change' link you click the edit `input` is only added to the first row.

To fix the first problem use unobtrusive event handlers with `data` attributes to hold the element metadata. To fix the second problem use common classes on all the repeated HTML structures along with DOM traversal methods to target them based on the `a` element which was clicked.

The corrected code would look like this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $template = $('#evaluation-template');

  $('.btn.change').on('click', e => {
    let $btn = $(e.target);
    let template = $template.html().replace('[courseid]', $btn.data('courseid')).replace('[addedbyuserid]', $btn.data('addedbyuserid')).trim();
    $btn.closest('.evaluation').html(template);
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.btn.save', e => {
    let $btn = $(e.target);
    console.log($btn.data('courseid'), $btn.data('addedbyuserid'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Username</th>
      <th scope="col">Course</th>
      <th scope="col">Grade</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>AddedByUser_1</td>
      <td>CourseName_1</td>
      <td class="d-flex justify-content-between evaluation">
        Grade_1
        <a class="btn btn-warning change" data-courseid="1" data-addedbyuserid="AddedByUserId_1">Change</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>AddedByUser_2</td>
      <td>CourseName_2</td>
      <td class="d-flex justify-content-between evaluation">
        Grade_2
        <a class="btn btn-warning change" data-courseid="1" data-addedbyuserid="AddedByUserId_2">Change</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>AddedByUser_3</td>
      <td>CourseName_3</td>
      <td class="d-flex justify-content-between evaluation">
        Grade_3
        <a class="btn btn-warning change" data-courseid="1" data-addedbyuserid="AddedByUserId_3">Change</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/template" id="evaluation-template">
  <label for="evaluation_input">Evaluate</label>
  <input class="evaluation_input" type="number" />
  <a class="btn btn-warning save" data-courseid="[courseid]" data-addedbyuserid="[addedbyuserid]">Save</a>
</script>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I noticed while building the snippet there's a couple of other issues in your code. I've just edited my answer to show you how to work around them with more modern techniques.

Comment: Thank you again!

Comment: I have a successfully ajax request. Would you tell me please, in "success: function (data) {
                        $btn.closest('.evaluation').html(data.evaluation);
                    }" how to add back Change button with correct evaluation, now I add only evaluation